# Combination the 2 Generic List

Tags: c#, generic-list

I have 2 Generic List:

```
List<Student> obj1 = new List<Student>();
List<Student> obj2 = new List<Student>();
```

I want Combination obj1 and obj2: obj1+obj2.

EX:

**obj1:**

---

```
1          remi         sistan

2          shaki        sistan
```

**obj2:**

---

```
3          nani         shahin

4          tina         shahin
```

**obj1 + obj2:**

---

```
1          remi         sistan

2          shaki        sistan

3          nani         shahin

4          tina         shahin
```

Answer (score 4):

Easy.

```
var list1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
var list2 = Enumerable.Range(10, 10).ToList();
var list3 = list1.Concat(list2).ToList();  //uses System.Linq
```

You can also do:

```
var list1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
var list2 = Enumerable.Range(10, 10).ToList();
list1.AddRange(list2);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about we do

```
List<Student> newobj = obj1.Concat(obj2).ToList();
```

For this you need to include namespace `System.Linq`

Answer (score 1):

`obj1.AddRange(obj2)` should be enough for you.

Make use of  [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Concatinate extention method that will return a new enumerable, or simply add the list2 into list1 like this:

obj1.AddRange(obj2);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.concat(List list)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894) method like so: `List<Student> con = obj1.Concat(obj2).ToList();`